# How to speed up generating pdf by Wicked gem in Rails

Tags: ruby, wicked-pdf

Services file:

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
          'ticket_managements/_render_pdf.html.erb',
          template: "ticket_managements/_render_pdf.html.erb",
          locals: { :ticket_order => ticket_order }
        ),
      )
```

When I try to generate over 30 pdf files, it takes 3 to 5 minutes. It's so bad and makes users mad

I also try to some other gem but as I researched and try with Benchmark, Wicked still is faster 
Or try to add `dpi` option, it stays that way

Any idea or solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try `wkhtmltopdf-heroku` gem?

Comment: There are 30 to 50 pages for each pdf. It takes over 3 minutes to finish.
I also try `wkhtmltopdf-heroku` gem already, it just improved a bit